# Пояснения по коду java graphics

Tags: java, графика, jframe

учу java, в частности застрял на примере по книге Сиерра К. Изучаем Java 2012г. стр 401.
В примере кода при нажатии на кнопку должен сгенирироваться новый градиентный цвет круга, за это отвечает

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            frame.repaint();
    }
```

Но у меня вылетает исключение Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Отсюда 2а вопроса...

1. Почему? ведь казалось бы я все сделал по книге...
2. Кто может дать пояснения по следующему... в кгине сказанно, что

   frame.repaint(); - Когда пользователь нажимает кнопку вызываем для фрейма метод repaint(). Это значит, что метод paintComponent() вызывается для каждого виджета во фрейме!

Каким образом вызывается метод public void paintComponent(Graphics g)? Ведь я же не вызываю его явно drawPanel.paintComponent(Graphics g); кто то может объяснить?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;


public class SimpleGui3C implements ActionListener {
    JButton frame;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleGui3C gui = new SimpleGui3C();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Сменить цвет круга"); 
        button.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
        
        MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();
        
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        //try {
            frame.repaint();
        //} catch (Exception e) {
        //  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        //  System.out.println(e.getStackTrace().toString());
        //}
    }
}

class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel{
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        Color startColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
        
        red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        Color endColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
        
        GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(70, 70, startColor, 150, 150, endColor);
        g2d.setPaint(gradient);
        g2d.fillOval(70, 70, 100, 100);
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на этот фрагмент кода:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        frame.repaint();
```

Здесь frame становится null, отсюда NullPointerException. Почему? Потому что вот здесь

```
public class Test implements ActionListener {
    JButton frame;
```

frame не инициализирован. Поэтому напишите так:

```
public class Test implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

и в методе go() уберите такую же строку

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

И заработает.

Если вы это скопировали из книжки/ресурса - все просто: авторы ошиблись. Или вы плохо переписали.

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало, на самом деле я допустил ошибку... 
'public class Test implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame;' (У меня вообще было JButton frame)
и в методе go 'frame = new JFrame;'

А у вас случайне нет соображений на вторую часть вопроса?

Comment: Посмотрите, мне кажется, вам понравится эта статья: https://ipsoftware.ru/posts/paint/

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу на второй ваш вопрос, если вы внимательно читали предыдущие главы этой книги. То там вы розбирали такую вещь как полиморфизм и интерфейсы. Так вот что-бы добавить елемент на JFrame он должен реализовывать интерфейс JPanel - отсюда следует что каждый елемент который мы можем добавлять во JFrame реализует этот интерфейс. Тогда не сложно догадатся как же все таки JFrame вызывает методы paintComponent().
Например у него в нутри скорее всего есть колекция обобщенная интерфейсным типом JPanel :

```
List<JPanel> jPanels = new ArrayList<>(); // можно представить что она выглядит так.
```

И как дальше не сложно понять в момент вызова метода нашего класа JFrame - repaint() мы переберем все елементы хранящиеся в этой колекции и вызовим метод paintComponent(Graphics g) каждого елемента. Примерно так и вам совсем не обязательно самому вызывать метод paintComponent(Graphics g). Лучше перечитайте предыдущие главы. Особенно 10 - 11.